# Oneplus2, screen capture option disappeared after OS upgrade

Tags: oneplus-two, oxygenos

I have a Oneplus2 device, recently (last week) I have upgrades the OS to OxygenOS 3.5.6. Among a lot of UI changes I have noticed that when I long press the power button I only get the "Power off" and "Reboot" options.

Before the OS upgrade It also contained a capture screen (for screenshots) button. Is there a way to bring it back ?

Comment: Looks like it's dropped. Apart from Vol dn + power option you have [3 finger swipe option](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwC_ui-wtBI)

Comment: If your device is rooted, it is possible

Comment: well, my device is not rooted.. yet! but i want to avoid having to install another widget/app just for that

Comment: In which case, you may not be able to *bring it back* as it is not a supported OS feature ( and needs root to modify OS) - I don't have that OS but a friend who has was discussing this option and showed me the three finger swipe

Comment: Just tried the 3 finger swipe and it's pretty good. post your solution as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: Posted as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is dropped from the OS update and you would need root pets to attempt restore or apply a hack. Since your device is not rooted, you can use [Three Finger Swipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwC_ui-wtBI) . Steps below :

Settings → Gestures → Enable Three Finger screenshot

By swiping the fingers from top down, you can take a screenshot. There's also an option of taking  a *long screenshot* by pressing the icon which looks like portrait device icon

I neither have the device nor OS, but saw it on a friend's device. Please feel free to add or edit